# Migrate web project from Webshpere 7.0 to Eclipse Java EE IDE / Tomcat 8.0

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, websphere, db2-400

I have to migrate a web project from Websphere to my personnal installation : 
Eclipse Java EE IDE / Tomcat 8.0.

I found some steps on several website, but nothing can help to solve my issue.
More specifiquely, some of those tutos says the exact opposite with other.

So, my serveur TOMCAT is running fine, I can get the fisrt page of my web application. The problem is with the connection with the database.
I tryed to solve it myself, but I definitely need some help.

Here are the issues : 
First, the log console give me this when I'm starting the server :

```
Apr 02, 2015 3:03:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\conf\Catalina\localhost\Context.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [/Context]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But its not cancel server starting.

But when a page need an acces to the database (AS400/DB2) its not working.
Please see below :

```
[BDD ERROR] Impossible d'ouvrir la connexion, ou connexion inutilisable: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource' for connect URL 'jdbc:as400://OLA'
[BDD ERROR] Impossible d'ouvrir la connexion, ou connexion inutilisable:     Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource' for connect URL 'jdbc:as400://OLA'
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource' for connect URL 'jdbc:as400://OLA'
java.lang.ClassCastException:  com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource cannot be cast to  java.sql.Driver
at  org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDat    aSource.java:2054)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1939)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)
at commun.TransactionBD.open(TransactionBD.java:189)
at commun.TransactionBD.execute(TransactionBD.java:295)
at outils.Traduction.getTraduction(Traduction.java:273)
at org.apache.jsp.Commun.Login.index_005fbis_jsp._jspService(index_005fbis_jsp.java:187)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:431)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone is able to help me with those problem? Do you need some conf / context files?

Thanks a lot for your help.

[EDIT]
Full startup log :

```
'Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:CGR_Server' did not find a matching property.
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 15 2015 18:10:42 UTC
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.20.0
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_05-b05
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\wtpwebapps
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\endorsed
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Emulator;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Astaro\Astaro SSL VPN Client\bin;.
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:55 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:55 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 678 ms
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\conf\Catalina\localhost\Context.xml
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester fatalError
SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 37: A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 37; A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPseudoAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanXMLDeclOrTextDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanXMLDeclOrTextDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$XMLDeclDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1476)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\conf\Catalina\localhost\Context.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 37; A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1476)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester fatalError
SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 37: A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/conf/Catalina/localhost/Context.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 37; A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPseudoAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanXMLDeclOrTextDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanXMLDeclOrTextDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$XMLDeclDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1457)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processContextConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in context.xml for /Context
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.20/conf/Catalina/localhost/Context.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 37; A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPseudoAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanXMLDeclOrTextDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanXMLDeclOrTextDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$XMLDeclDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1457)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processContextConfig
SEVERE: Occurred at line 1 column 37
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [/Context]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to process either the global, per-host or context-specific context.xml file therefore the [/Context] Context cannot be started.
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext.startInternal(FailedContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\conf\Catalina\localhost\Context.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [/Context]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\conf\Catalina\localhost\Context.xml has finished in 26 ms
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\docs
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:58 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\docs has finished in 368 ms
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\examples
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\examples has finished in 663 ms
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\host-manager
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\host-manager has finished in 301 ms
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\manager
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\manager has finished in 255 ms
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\ROOT
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\ROOT has finished in 242 ms
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 02, 2015 3:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4548 ms'
```

[EDIT2] And the file "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\conf\Catalina\localhost\Context.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<Context path="/CGR" docbase="CGR">
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/OLA" 
   type="com.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2SimpleDataSource" 
      global="jdbc/OLA">
</Context>
```

Comment: Is that *all* of the server output at startup? Seems like there should be more.

Comment: No, you're right.
Please check the edit in my question for all the startup log

Comment: Have you migrated your JDBC DataSource configuration from WAS to Tomcat?

Comment: Hi Steve C, english is my second language, and I'm not sure to understand what you mean.
If you ask if jt400.jar library is in the lib folder of my tomcat home directory, yes.

Comment: Looks like a parsing problem with C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\conf\Catalina\localhost\Context.xml . Can you show its contents?

Comment: Hi nitind, sorry I can show you anything until monday, everything is at work, I'll do it asap on monday. =)

Comment: Good morning you all,
Pleaqse check my initial post to find the file :  C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\conf\Catalina\localhost\Context.xml

Answer (score 0):

We have a UCP(Universal Connection Pool) with Tomcat whitepaper where the necessary configurations to get Oracle database connection is present.

Please refer to the below whitepaper. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-tomcat-2265175.pdf